# Bot that change twitter profile picture

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, bots

Hey there I'd like to code a bot with nodejs to change a profile picture

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var data = require('fs').readFileSync('image1.png');

var client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: 'asd',
    consumer_secret: 'asd',
    access_token: 'asd',
    access_token_secret: 'asd'
});

client.post('account/update_profile_image', {image: data},  function(error, tweet, response) {
  console.log("done");  // Raw response object.
});
```

well it seems to work but my profile picture does not change

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to work but my profile picture does not change" ? That sounds broken to me. Are you seeing any errors? Is there anything helpful if you debug and evaluate variables?

Comment: @JeffMergler well when i execute the code, there is no error but nothing happen on my profile picture

Comment: Have you read the documentation ? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/post-account-update_profile_image.html : "The avatar image for the profile, base64-encoded. Must be a valid GIF, JPG, or PNG image of less than 700 kilobytes in size. Images with width larger than 400 pixels will be scaled down."

Comment: @JeffProd yes to try i change my actual profile pic for another one, and tried to update it with the "normal" one i use, but it didn't take effect and i don't see any error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the documentation, the image must be base64 encoded. Here is a working code :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Twit = require('twit'); // npm install twit

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         '*',
    consumer_secret:      '*',
    access_token:         '*',
    access_token_secret:  '*'
});

var image64str = fs.readFileSync('kitten.jpg', {encoding: 'base64'});

T.post('account/update_profile_image', { image: image64str }, function(err) {
    if(err) {console.error(err); return;}
    console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: thanks dude, sorry for misleading lol i'm not very good at that i was thinking that i can use directly an image that was a profil picture

Comment: i got another error "JSON decode error: Twitter HTTP response body was not valid JSON'" you didnt got any error ?

Comment: No, i did'nt have errors. Please try "npm install twit".

Comment: i delete the version i have and re-installed it and it works thanks idk why it doesn't wanted to work before